# Receiving a Traceback error while using gingerit in python

Tags: python

I have a startup code to use gingerit on python. Gingerit is by far the most enhanced and the best grammar tool available on python. When I try running the code I have, I started receiving a traceback error.I am currently using 3.7 and the code I used is present on the official gingerit documentation.

```
text = 'it is there problem'
parser = GingerIt()
parser.parse(text)
```

I expected to not have any errors on this but there was a traceback error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sid071/Desktop/gingerit.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gingerit.gingerit import GingerIt
  File "C:/Users/sid071/Desktop\gingerit.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gingerit.gingerit import GingerIt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gingerit.gingerit'; 'gingerit' is not a package
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is called gingerit, which is hiding the package you installed. Rename your script to something else.

Comment: I tried changing my scripts name but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the module using this code:

```
pip install --force --no-cache-dir  --upgrade playlistfromsong
```